# Firefox: why beforeunload triggered when cursor in input and enter key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

My codes:

```
  13 module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
  14   tagName: 'div',
  15   events: {
  16     'click #addQuery': '_handleQuery',
  17     'click #clearScreenBtn': '_handleClearScreen',
  26   },
  27 
  28   initialize(options) {
  62     $(window).on('beforeunload', () => {
  74     });
  75   },
```

HTML:

```
<input id="titleInput" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Report" type="text">
```

beforeunload supposed to be triggered when URL clicked. But why it is triggered on **firefox**, when cursor in in input (id="titleInput" above) and **ENTER** key pressed. This did not happen in **Chrome**.

When cursor is after ddd in the following pic:
[image]

after **ENTER** key pressed:
[image]

Anything missing? Thanks.

Comment: Is the input field inside a `<form>`? Pressing Enter submits the form, which reloads the page from the form response.

Comment: why not happened in chrome？thanks

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome, I got the warning about leaving the page.

Comment: My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/91wa6r91/

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. You are right. Thanks